# Given matrices $A,B$ of order $3 \times 3$ such that $AB=0$ prove that $\rho(A)+\rho(B) \leq3$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Given matrices $A,B$ of order $3 \times 3$ such that $AB=0$ prove that $\rho(A)+\rho(B) \leq3$
>
> Does a matrix exist such that $A,B$ are of order $3 \times 3$ and $AB=0$ and $\rho(BA)=2$
>
> Note - $\rho=rank$

---

I want to know if there exists a different proof other than what the textbook did .

The solution in the textbook:

define $B=(b_{ij})$ . if $AB=0$ then for every $j$ $(1 \leq j \leq 3)$ we get $(AB)_J^c=AB_j^c=0$ which leads to that the column $B_j^c$ is the solution to the homogenous system $Ax=0$ therefore the column space $W_B^C$ of B is in the solution space of $Ax=0$ , which we will define as $P(A)$ so $W_B^C \subseteq P(A)$ from here we get $\rho(B)=dimW(B_j^C) \leq dimP(A)$ or $\rho(B) \leq 3- \rho(A)$ and from here $\rho(A)+\rho(B) \leq 3$

this is the solution in the textbook ( hopefully my translations are right and it is understandable) I was wondering if there is another way for this?

I tried this way but got stuck since $AB=0$ then we know that $\det(A) \cdot \det(B)=0$ so $\det(A)=0$ or $\det(B)=0$
therefore we know one of them has atleast one zero row so $\rho(A)+\rho(B) \leq 5$  but I cannot think of a way to continue to assure that $\rho(A)+\rho(B) \leq 3$

for the second question if such matrix exists it is not true , given $\rho(A)+\rho(B) \leq 3$ such that $AB=0$ and $\rho(BA)=2$ we get that $\rho(A)+\rho(B) \geq 4$ which is a contradiction to $\rho(A)+\rho(B) \leq 3$

Thank s for any tips and help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A more general fact is true. If $AB=0$ for $n\times n$ matrices then the sum of ranks is less than or equal $n.$ If $p(B)=k$ then the image of $B$ is $k$ dimensional. Therefore the kernel of $A$ is at least $k$ dimensional. Hence the rank of $A$ is at most $n-k.$